# Display image in table row in dependency of object.name

Tags: angular

I have a table with a bunch of data. In the first table row, i'd like to be an image of the device in dependency of the devices name. So i have an object. So this is my table row setup:

```
<tr class="pointer" *ngFor="let hardware of hardwareForCustomerName; let i = index;" (click)="goToDetails(hardwareForCustomerName[i].barcode)">
    <th scope="row">{{ hardwareForCustomerName[i].serial }}</th>
    <td>{{ hardwareForCustomerName[i].type.deviceType.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ hardwareForCustomerName[i].installedAtBranch.name }}</td>
    <td>
      <span *ngFor="let interface of hardwareForCustomerName[i].type.interfaces; let isLast = last">
            {{ interface.name }}{{ isLast ? '' : ', ' }}
      </span>
    </td>
    <td>{{ hardwareForCustomerName[i].type.readMethod.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ hardwareForCustomerName[i].dateSent | date : "dd.MM.yyyy" }}</td>
</tr>
```

So where now `{{ hardwareForCustomerName[i].type.deviceType.name }}` is i'd like to show an image in dependency of what the name is. When the name is `foo` i'd like to show foo.png and when the name is `bar` bar.png should appear - how can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<td>
    <img src="my/directory/{{hardwareForCustomerName[i].type.deviceType.name}}.png" alt="">
</td>
```

Comment: `.name` != image name :-/ Name is sth like "Hardware Mig 4.9" and image name is sth. like hw_mig_49_thumb.png

Comment: You have to make somekind of transform method to create the name of the image from the name. Then you can use it in your template like this: `src="my/directory/{{transformName(hardwareForCustomerName[i].type.deviceType.name)}}.png"`